# Cannot interact with my Raspberry Pi running 20.10 from Ubuntu computer but I can do it with a Mac

Tags: networking, server, ssh, raspberrypi

I recently distro-hopped from Raspbian to Ubuntu MATE 20.10 and I enabled the SSH service. I can connect it from a Mac (not with Ubuntu), but it doesn't even allow interactions from my computer. Whenever I ping it, it tells me that Destination Host is Unreachable (from the same IP address as my Ubuntu laptop). SSHing it says that the connection timed out. This is also the case vice-versa.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. This is my first post in Stack Exchange (let alone askubuntu), so if there are any flaws with this, please let me know.

EDIT:

- Yes, `openssh-server` was downloaded and activated. Sorry for not clarifying.
- My Mac is connnected via ethernet. The rest of the devices are connected wirelessly.
- I ping both of my devices by supplying the IP address.
- If needed, my Raspberry Pi was set in router settings to have the IP address of  `192.168.1.76` by default. My laptop has the IP address of `192.168.1.86`, and my Mac has the IP address of `192.168.1.75`. I will provide commands logs in a bit.

Comment: It is difficult to say without a little more info, can you provide more information, network address of Mac, Pi and Ubuntu machines (available as the output of `ifconfig` How is each connected, Mac = Wifi? Pi = ?, ubuntu = ? Are you pinging by name or supplying the IP address?

Comment: @SEWTGIYWTKHNTDS Editing accordingly. I'll get around to expand on the network addresses when I have more time. Many apologies.

Comment: OK, I think that your Mac can ping both the ubuntu and pi.  But the Pi can't ping ubuntu and vice versa.  I think that your wireless router is set to prevent wireless clients from communicating with each other, but they can communicate with the wired segment.  Try looking at your router configuration it should have a setting for this.

Comment: May I ask where specifically I can find this in? (e.g. the firewall configuration,  LAN IP settings, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a stupid solution, but it worked for me nonetheless.

If you have two internet connections (with each having the same IP addresses corresponding to the same devices), connect to another one and check if you can connect to it. This feels a bit scummy though, and my second connection is slower for some reason, so if you guys have any other solutions, then post it here. I won't put this as the solution.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong in the first place with having two different network interfaces with the same IP address (if I understood you correctly). I'd say such setup is guaranteed to not work.

Comment: @raj That is true. That is why I didn't fully approve this answer.

Comment: So why do you have such a setup? Reconfigure it to get rid of duplicate addresses.

Comment: Late reply. It's because one router's in my basement and the other is on another floor. I'll try to reconfigure it.